# Library to communicate with multiple platforms including Windows Forms, ASP and Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, xamarin.forms

I'm doing a project that requires reading an API into multiple platforms (there include: Windows Forms, ASP and Xamarin Forms PCL) I can do that separately, although I want to have something that I can do it all just once and just call method from each platform. But the thing is, I've been doing some tests and doing some research and looks like that is no class library that is compatible with all these three, at least.

So, I've been wondering, is there any alternative thatn just having to do it all separately? I mean, between ASP and Windows Forms would work just fine, but Xamarin is a whole different story.

Anyway, I'd appreciate any help given.

Comment: If you gave an example of what you were trying to do, that might help to provide an answer you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the .Net Standard, and it would work for all. (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/)

You will need to create a Portable library (PCL) or a .net core library that will follow the .net standard. You will not have access to the whole functionality of the full .net framework, but it will work

Comment: Hi, thanks. That's a great solution! Although it still isn't 100%. I mean, I still can't get things like being able to do sqlconnections (or so it seems to me). I get error saying that system.data.sqlclient isn't referenced. So, I add a reference through the object browser and the using statement. It is already recognized. Great. But I still get errors. And in other things as well. I can only target until version 1.4 before getting errors on some platform. But 1.4 does indeed connect to all those I need it to.

Comment: So, I want to know if there's any way to get aroung this or if I always have to use it just as a bridge between the specific library and the platforms. P.S: I'm targetting the one that says "Class Library (Portable for iOS, Android and Windows)".

Comment: I had to install the Sytem.Data.SqlClient Nugget Package. It's working, now. Yet, it seems there's much that isn't supported. For instance, System.Net.Mail. It doesn't seem to work, amongst others. So, I guess the best thing is to actually use this a brigde between platforms. What do you think?

Comment: The thing is that right now the .Net is fragmented. This is why they established the .Net standard

Comment: You have the "full" .Net framework(like 4.6.1), the mono-Xamarin .Net platform and the .Net Core platform. Microsoft already announced that they will concentrate to support only .Net core, but right now, .Net Core has only parts from the full framework implemented. The same with Xamarin. This is why they established the .Net standard, to define all the functionalities that are implemented on all platform. For example System.Net mail is missing, because is missing from a platform, so in any case this can't work on all platforms no matter what you use.

Comment: I've been experimenting and I ketp a portable class library I'd already finished (indows library) and created a "Class Library (Portable for iOS, Android and Windows)" and targetted the .NET Standard 1.4 and used it as a bridge between platforms. For instance, I call a funtction from the bidge library, which, in turn, calls the respactive function from main class library. That way, I can keep doing the same on a windows platform without worrying about compatibility. I can even send e-mails that way from either platform, be it ASP, Windows Forms or Xamarin.Forms. :)  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should write a common class file and add it to other projects as "add file as link" and manage them with preprocessor directives if there are differents (and of course there are differences :) )

What i'm trying to say this i have 3 projects and all makes api calls to same RESTapi. I have the main class in my first project and added it to 2 others via "right click->add->add existing item->'select the file'->add as link" button. And write the code specific code with preprcessor directives. Like

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
#if __IOS__
using CoreGraphics;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
#endif
#if __ANDROID__
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Util;
using View = Android.Views.View;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using RelativeLayout = Android.Widget.RelativeLayout;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Views.Animations;
#endif
namespace Mobile.Helpers
{
    public static class DialogHelper
    {
        var result = CallApi(); //so this will be common
        #if __IOS__
        //create ios view etc. and use result
        #if __ANDROID__
        //create android view etc. and use result
        #endif

    }
}
```

So you can write your code; for example Net.Mail codes in a

```
#if __WINDOWS__
#endif
```

directives and it will be compiled on only windows project. And write specific code for the other platforms. 
So you need to update (and take care) only one file for a specific job.

I used this to show a custom notification popup (view) for android and ios but you can use it for anything for any kind of project. Hope it is clear enough to understand.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Looks like a good alteranative. Although, I ended up doing the .NET Standard way, as suggested in the other answer. It's working great. But thanks! :)